# How to use Facebook SDK with SvelteKit?

Tags: sveltekit

I'm new to Sveltekit, and I need to add Facebook authorisation to my website. I am using TypeScript in my project. Maybe some of you have experience with Facebook authorisation in SvelteKit. I don't understand how exactly and in which file to initialise the FB variable. I have read the documentation from developers.facebook.com

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '{your-app-id}',
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : '{api-version}'
    });
      
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();   
      
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

I added this code inside the head in my app.html fil. But the FB variable is still not available in my components.
What I would ideally like to get is this:
I have a SignIn component, here is some of its code:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import FacebookBtn from "./FacebookBtn.svelte";

</script>
<div class="page-container">
        <div class="form">
            <picture class="logo ">
                <source srcset="https://gitlab.trisgram.com/trisgram/company-graphics/-/raw/main/Identity/3gram_logo_transparent_128px.avif" type="image/avif"> 
                <img src="https://gitlab.trisgram.com/trisgram/company-graphics/-/raw/main/Identity/3gram_logo_transparent.png " alt="logo" class="logo">
            </picture>
            <h1>Sign in</h1>
            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" bind:value={username} />
                <i class='bx bx-user'></i>
            </div>
            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" bind:value={password} />
                <i class='bx bx-lock-alt'></i>
                
            </div>
            
            <button class="button2" on:click={forgotPassword}>Forgot password?</button>
            
            <FacebookBtn/> 
            <!-- <button class="button1" on:click={handleLogin}>Sign in</button> -->
            <a href="/profile/profilePage">Sign in</a>

            <div class="buttonWithText">
                <p>Don't have account?</p>
                <a href="/sign-up">Sign up</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

In this component is created FacebookBtn inside this button is the logic of authorisation through facebook, respectively when you click it should be authorised. The main problem is that "Cannot find name 'FB'" Even though I initialised it in app.html.
I allow the option that Facebook javascript sdk doesn't work with typescript at all in that case, how do I avoid problems if my project is on typescript

I also tried to create a file globlas.d.ts, and in it declare the variable FB

```
declare global {

    
    interface Window {
        FB: any; 
    }

    
}
```

but it doesnt help. I have a feeling I'm missing something, but I haven't found anywhere examples of creating an app on SvelteKit with Facebook SDK. Please, if you want to help,write in detail in which file and in which part of the project the code should be located, because I am new to SvelteKit. Thanks for understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load the Facebook SDK, FB becomes a property of the global object. Simply console.log(window) & you'll see the FB property.

With SvelteKit, you can instantiate FB in onMount, like so:

```
let FB:any;
onMount(
   ()=> {
    const windowRef:any = window // so that you don't get an 
    error by calling window.FB if you're using Typescript
    
    if(typeof windowRef.FB !== 'undefined'){
      FB = windowRef.FB;
    }

    //... you could also do this:
    const global:any = globalThis; // if using Typescript
    setTimeout( ()=>  FB = global.FB, 0)
);
```

No doubt there are other ways to handle this, but the general idea is that FB becomes a property of the global object.